# membership provider using ravenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, membership-provider

I'm trying to implement .net membership provider which uses ravenDB. I already set raven db inside my mvc4 application and I think I'm setup correctly membership provider for use ravenDB except calling document store from membership provider. Example which I found uses following

```
 public IDocumentStore DocumentStore
        {
            get
            {
                if (documentStore == null)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The DocumentStore is not set. Please set the DocumentStore or make sure that the Common Service Locator can find the IDocumentStore and call Initialize on this provider.");
                }
                return this.documentStore;
            }
            set { this.documentStore = value; }
        }
```

Since I'm already set document store in my mvc project inside global.asax file

```
public static IDocumentStore DocumentStore { get; private set; }
        private static void CreateRavenDBDocumentStore()
        {
            DocumentStore = new DocumentStore
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"
            }.Initialize();
        }
```

inside

```
Application_Start(){
    CreateRavenDBDocumentStore();
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to use this code snippet from my global.asax.cs file for creating document store which will use call from MembershipProvider?

Hope I was not too confused :)

Thanks

Comment: I think it's not a good idea at all to use Raven to stroe membership Data. In production SQL has a better reliability and validity too.

Comment: Mostly as an aside, there are a few RavenDB membership providers already out there, e.g. [on GitHub](https://github.com/wilby/RavenDBMembership) or [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Raven.AspNetProviders/)

Comment: @RobertP I know Mongo better than Raven but you ought to get enough consistency using majority writes. The only real issue I can think of is not seeing a password change reflected instantly if you don't have sticky sessions and the web server somehow flips to a secondary but I expect that's pretty rare, and membership data is so rarely changed you can go the extra mile to make sure it is written consistently.

Comment: I use MongoDB for volatile unimportant things like top offer retargeting on landingpages. Very cool in this scenario, ultra fast. And no problem if all the data is invalid or gets lots.

Comment: And raven too for nservicebus saga persistance. I switched to SQL after the first persitence problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good project and write up of using ravendb membership provider with mvc.You could refer [this project](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2010/11/25/raven-db-asp-net-membership-provider/) which i used in my case.